# Servicestack FallbackRoute not recognizing trailing slash

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, servicestack

So, the ServiceStack FallbackRoute in my code is [FallbackRoute("/{Path*}/")], which is the setup that the ServiceStack documentation says will handle every unmatched route.

If given a route like example.com/api then it will trigger the fallback response correctly.

However if given example.com/api/ then it just returns an empty 200 OK response.

It does handle unmatched routes with content after the slash correctly, so example.com/api/arglkjadkf will be sent to the fallback

I want Servicestack to be able to take the url with the trailing slash after the base path and have it hit the fallback route.

Comment: Not really an answer as I never did figure out what was causing ServiceStack to not catch the route with trailing slash, but i did eventually resolve this by hardcoding an MVC route for api/, and leaving ServiceStack to deal with the other unmatched api routes.

Answer (score -1):

ServiceStack doesn't distinguish trailing slashes as different routes, i.e:

```
[Route("/api")]
```

Handles both `/api` and `/api/`

So there shouldn't be a trailing slash in your route definitions and since you're using a wildcard path, i.e:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{PathInfo*}")]
public class FallbackForUnmatchedRoutes
{
    public string PathInfo { get; set; }
}
```

This will handle any routes of any depth that are not already handled.

Comment: That's actually the setup i had originally, i had tried the fallbackroute with a trailing slash to see what would happen and forgot to remove it when pasting into the stackoverflow question. Unfortunately either way doesn't impact the behavior of /api/. I'm wondering now if there is some interference from the MVC routing that handles a different part of the application, but I can't figure out what. I don't see anything that should be interfering with ServiceStack's route like that.